# Filtering table output based on the column sum

Tags: r

I want to filter a table output based on sum of its values, in this case, column values. Then I want to create a barplot for those values higher than certain sums.

Code:

```
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
counts
#output
#x  3  4  5
#0 12  2  4
#1  3 10  1

#I want to create a barplot for those with column sums > 12 ie. gears 3 and 4.

#pseudo-code
#barplot(counts[colSums>12]?
```

My expected output is that it will show barplot with only 2 columns for gears 3 and 4. How to do that in R?

PS: I can create find the number of gears for every cars (`table(mtcars$gear)`), subset those with sum > 12, then create another `table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)` to create barplot with 2 columns but I am looking if there is any immediate way to do that.

Comment: Pretty close in your pseudo code: `barplot(counts[,colSums(counts) >= 12]`.

Comment: Thanks. This is kinda what I was looking for. I didn't find anything about subsetting table in the R documentation though. I didnt know that we can do `table[,filtering-criteria]`. Any more docs I can read for R's table?

Comment: More or less, all R objects can be subset with `[`, though there are some exceptions with more esoteric or complex objects. tabular type objects, (matrix, table, and data.frame, probably others) can be subset with `[ , ]` and arrays in the straightforward extension. When in doubt, give it a try. I guess the tip with `?table` is in the Value section where it says that the function returns an array. See `?[` for a discussion on subsetting and extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One ggplot2 solution,

```
# install.packages(c("ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, gear <= 4), aes(factor(vs)))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(gear)))
```

[image: gear 3 and 4 ggplot2]

Or as per [lmo's comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543520/filtering-table-output-based-on-the-column-sum#comment80041163_46543520)

```
counts <- with(mtcars, table(vs, gear)) 
counts

barplot(counts[,colSums(counts) >= 12])
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks both of you. Both are really the answer I am looking for. I was expecting Imo's likes of answers which give me another table but Eric's answer gives me another perspective using ggplot too.